# Java 2d game cross-platform compatability

Tags: java, 2d, ios, cross-platform

I need to make a few small, simple 2d educational games primarily to help kids improve their reading. Drag & drop/matching words with pictures, spelling out words as well as maybe a scrolling shooter and some other things too. I also need these to run on multiple platforms (namely windows, osx, ipads and android).

If I do this with java (which I don’t currently know), is it possible to use the same code to create versions compatible with the above-mentioned platforms?

Comment: You should look to libgdx (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/), it offers much you are asking for: develop with java and deploy on androd, desktop, ios. It's a big community and you can fine some nice demos around.

Comment: I'd like to make sure people know before answering, this is not a "Which technology to use" question. Answers that are just suggestions for libraries or engines to use will be removed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A Java application works on any common desktop operating system.

Android applications are written in Java, but are structured very differently than normal desktop applications. Also, most standard Java GUI toolkits aren't supported by Android. So porting to Android will require much more work than just clicking a button.

On iOS, Java isn't supported at all.

Did you consider building your game as a web application? Every device nowadays has a web browser which can execute Javascript, so you can't get much more plattform-independent than that.

Comment: Thanks that's a good point.  Could this be used even when offline assuming you had all the files?

Comment: @SirPsychoSexy As long as your game doesn't require any server-sided programming, it will work locally.